# cap production deploy fails with ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL: database "rails/rbwapp" does not exist

Tags: deployment, digital-ocean, ubuntu-20.04, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an empty Rails application working on my development machine.
I have been following the tutorial at https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/20.04 in order to deploy it to a new DigitalOcean ubuntu 20.04 droplet.

I work my way through the entire entire tutorial and get to the step where I run the deploy:

```
ThinkPad-T570:~/rails/rbwapp$ cap production deploy  
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.110s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-rbwapp-production-rbw.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-rbwapp-production-rbw.sh
    ✔ 02 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.063s

00:00 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:rwaddington/rbwapp.git HEAD
      01 0d717f41d83befe63856ddf6cfdf4d808519a1dc   HEAD
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.795s
00:01 deploy:check:directories
      01 mkdir -p /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.059s
00:01 deploy:check:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/log /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/tmp/pids /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/tmp/cache /…
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.100s
00:01 git:clone
      The repository mirror is at /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/repo
00:01 git:update
      01 git remote set-url origin git@github.com:rwaddington/rbwapp.git
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.107s
      02 git remote update --prune
      02 Fetching origin
    ✔ 02 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.820s
00:02 git:create_release
      01 mkdir -p /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.106s
      02 git archive master | /usr/bin/env tar -x -f - -C /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348
    ✔ 02 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.074s
00:03 deploy:set_current_revision
      01 echo "0d717f41d83befe63856ddf6cfdf4d808519a1dc" > REVISION
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.061s
00:03 deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
      01 mkdir -p /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348 /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/tmp /home/rbw/rails/…
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.102s
      02 rm -rf /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/log
    ✔ 02 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.060s
      03 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/log /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/log
    ✔ 03 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.104s
      04 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/tmp/pids /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/tmp/pids
    ✔ 04 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.055s
      05 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/tmp/cache /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/tmp/cache
    ✔ 05 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.107s
      06 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/tmp/sockets /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/tmp/sockets
    ✔ 06 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.065s
      07 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/vendor/bundle /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/vendor/bundle
    ✔ 07 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.105s
      08 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/.bundle /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/.bundle
    ✔ 08 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.061s
      09 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/public/system /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/public/system
    ✔ 09 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.106s
      10 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/public/uploads /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/public/uploads
    ✔ 10 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.063s
      11 ln -s /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/public/assets /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/public/assets
    ✔ 11 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.105s
00:05 bundler:config
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle config --local deployment true
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.389s
      02 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle config --local path /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/shared/bundle
    ✔ 02 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.514s
      03 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle config --local without development:test
    ✔ 03 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.607s
00:07 bundler:install
      The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied, skipping installation
00:08 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 yarn install v1.22.5
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
      01 info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
      01 info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
      01 info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
      01 info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 Done in 13.85s.
      01 yarn install v1.22.5
      01 [1/4] Resolving packages...
      01 [2/4] Fetching packages...
      01 info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
      01 info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
      01 info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
      01 info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
      01 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
      01 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
      01 Done in 7.12s.
      01 Compiling...
      01 Compiled all packs in /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/public/packs
      01 Hash: 666d45eeef50ba415ec8
      01 Version: webpack 4.44.1
      01 Time: 9726ms
      01 Built at: 08/28/2020 5:04:31 PM
      01                                         Asset       Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
      01        js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js   69.3 KiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  application
      01     js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js.br   15.3 KiB          [emitted]
      01     js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js.gz   17.7 KiB          [emitted]
      01    js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js.map    205 KiB       0  [emitted] [dev]        application
      01 js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js.map.br     44 KiB          [emitted]
      01 js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js.map.gz     51 KiB          [emitted]
      01                                 manifest.json  364 bytes          [emitted]
      01                              manifest.json.br  129 bytes          [emitted]
      01                              manifest.json.gz  142 bytes          [emitted]
      01 Entrypoint application = js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js js/application-dd6e88065a32b23f8e21.js.map
      01 [0] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 552 bytes {0} [built]
      01 [1] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 742 bytes {0} [built]
      01 [5] ./app/javascript/channels/index.js 205 bytes {0} [built]
      01 [6] ./app/javascript/channels sync _channel\.js$ 160 bytes {0} [built]
      01     + 3 hidden modules
      01
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 36.283s
00:44 deploy:assets:backup_manifest
      01 mkdir -p /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/assets_manifest_backup
    ✔ 01 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.107s
      02 cp /home/rbw/rails/rbwapp/releases/20200828170348/public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-36bf47d96af8c04d2269f7a55275b52a.json /…
    ✔ 02 rbw@64.225.88.53 0.064s
00:44 deploy:migrate
      [deploy:migrate] Run `rake db:migrate`
00:44 deploy:migrating
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 rake aborted!
      01 ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "rails/rbwapp" does not exist
... stackdump omitted ...
```

The error is correct in the sense that database "rails/rbwapp" doesn't exist, but it's also not supposed to. It should be looking for "rbwapp_production" (which does exist)

I'm stuck. Any suggestions greatly appreciated...

Comment: Have you created the database on the server?, If no, the login to the server using shell and create the database and again execute `cap production deploy`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but "rails/rbwapp" is the path to my app root and not a database.

Comment: got it, paste your database.yml which is on the server

Comment: Thank you again for your help, but since the deploy failed, there is no config/database.yml on the server. But this issue can be closed. I went back and recreated from scratch both my server, and my rails app, and *finally* got "cap production deploy" to work after a bit of struggle. I have not idea where I went wrong with my first attempt, but I have it up and running on the server now. Thanks again!